# Header (background) image not resizing when container margins are all relative

Tags: html, css

My team and I are making a website for an archery competition. We want to use our logo as a `header`, but the image has been causing us troubles: the image won't resize to fit our needs and keeps duplicating inside the container. Now, we are not wizards, but we have been searching for an answer. We have found many solutions on this website regarding resizing header images, but none of them were applicable to our problem, due to our container sizes being all-relative and the solutions we found were all aboslute. What I mean is that our container sizes in CSS are all relative, but in the solutions, they weren't.

This is my CSS work on it.

```
#header {

    background-image:url('../files/ifaa_dutch_open_logo.jpg');
    height: 40%;
    width: 96%;
    top: 2%;
    left: 2%;
    border-radius:15px;
    float:center;
    position:relative;

}
```

This is the corresponding HTML-code:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

To further illustrate what is happening, here's a picture:
[The picture](http://i58.tinypic.com/25rlfgp.png)

What is wrong here? We want the image to resize to fit the container, but it won't. The ratio doesn't seem to matter, for I have also tried it on a new page, where the image was exactly 1/4 of the container, it would just show four pictures, in each corner.

What are we doing wrong and how can we fix this?

Comment: In order to gain the full value of our knowledge, please post a demo that exhibits the behavior including all relevant HTML, CSS, JS, etc. within a reasonable and minimal amount. jsFiddle.net is our go to site for posting code.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as accepted if one of them helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I way I see it, your main problem is that the image is repeating itself, and as a result, it unable to fit the container properly. Try:

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you very much for your help! It worked, the image is no longer repeating itself.